# Facebook Object Debugger says website is inacessible - but it isn't

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

On this page: http://megascope.dk/Level7Marathon facebook comments were added by a friend. Commenting works great, everything looks fine.

He asked me why he gets no moderation-options on the page, even though he is added as a moderator in fb:admins as usual , so I checked it out in object debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmegascope.dk%2FLevel7Marathon

Even though the page is completely visible, there are no access restrictions whatsoever - object debugger returns this error:

[image]

"The page at http://invalid.invalid/ could not be reached."

I am guessing the two problems are related.

Does anybody know what causes this - and how we can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fixed itself after some days like many other odd facebook bugs. Something like that seems to happen every time I deal with integrating some facebook social plugin into a website.